# Continuity on the domain

Tags: real-analysis

> We have the following function $$f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
>     \sqrt{x^2+x+4}+4,&  x\leq -1\\
>     \dfrac{2x^3-2x^2-4x}{(x^2-1)(x-2)},              & x > -1, x \neq 1, x \neq 2
> \end{cases}
>  $$
>
> Now define a function $g$ such that$$g(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
>     f(x),&  x\neq 1, x \neq2\\
>    c,              & x=2
> \end{cases}
>  $$
>
> Does there exist a number $c$ such that $g(x)$ is continuous in $x=2$. And is $g$ than continuous on ($-\infty,1) \cup (1, \infty)? $

So to tackle this problem I first proved that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 4$, so if you choose $c=4$ then you have $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = f(2) =4 $, so yes, for $c=4$, the function $g(x)$ is continuous in $x=2$. Is this correct?

I'm also not sure if it's continuous everywhere, since $x=1$ is not in the domain. The limit $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ also doesn't exist, so it shouldn't be continuous there, but it's not in the domain so I don't know if you can say the function $g(x)$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Notice again what the question says:

> Does there exist a number $c$ such that $g(x)$ is continuous in $x=2$. And is $g$ than continuous on ($-\infty,1) \cup (1, \infty)? $

Your choice for $c$ does make $g(x)$ continuous for $x=2$, as you have proven. Further, if $f(x)$ is continuous on $ (-\infty,1) \cup (1, 2) \cup (2, \infty)$ and you have made the point $x=2$ continuous then $g(x)$ *is* continuous on ($-\infty,1) \cup (1, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how $g$ behaves at $1$ because $1$ has been specifically excluded from the set you are checking continuity on. However, it does matter how $g$ behaves at other points, and there is another point than $2$ and $1$ where something potentially non-continuous happens. You had better look there.

Comment: Do you mean -1? Because from my calculations it's continuous there.

Comment: Best check again, the limit from the left is 6, from the right is 1.